# When I press the enter key in google search bar, instead of searching the keyword, it creates a new line

Tags: search, google-search

This is a new issue that whenever I write something to search in google and press enter key, it starts a new line.
As per the below website saying I have cleared cookies and cache and the problem is fixed. This issue comes again after 2 or 3 days.
Is there a way to completely stop this annoying issue.
info link: https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/214566929/when-i-press-enter-on-google-search-bar-instead-of-searching-it-enters-a-new-line-how-do-i-set-it?hl=en

Comment: It might depend on the browser and extensions you use. Most of the cases are caused by extensions. And suspiciously most of them are caused by ad blockers. Have you tried on another browser, or tried checking the extensions you used?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. It was not being caused by any adblocker but one extension called '`Enable Copy Paste`' (`ECP`). I think it was interfering with the shift key because, default behavior of the google page input box is to multiline when pressing 'shift+enter' and not just 'enter' key. Disabling ECP caused google search input to work normally again! What an annoyance it was for many weeks because google search is itself getting more frustrating.